# ngCordova, download load multiple files with AngularJS Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on an angular cordvoa app that downloads files via an api. I'm using the `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` to handle the downloads. However, the downloads take longer than what's being passed to the function.

I looking at using the `$q` that gives me access to `promise`.

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(fileUrl, filePath+fileName, {}, true)
.then(function (result) {
    //console.log(result);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
}, function (progress) {
    //console.log(progress);
});
```

When I run some console logs showing how things are being processes I can see that multiple files are being passed to the above before it's finished and the function runs the most recent passed files.

I need to basically set up a queue so each file can be downloaded on a first come first serve.

--- edit ---

A bit more simple:

I'm building a Cordova app using Angular. So, I'm utilizing ngCordova.

I have an function that takes an array, gets file urls from the array, and passes the url, location to download, and filename to another function.

The second function downloads the file with the `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` plugin. Files are being passed to the function faster than the download happens. I need to setup a queue so I can download the files one at a time.

AngularJS has the `$q` method that gives me access to `promise`. How/Can I use `promise` to queue the files so I don't miss any?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: You can use Promise-Chaining to execute downloads in sequence. Have a look at https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences . I know, this is not Angular, but the way to do it is the same. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: what did you end up doing?